# How to display the image I click on in my modal?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, image, stimulusjs

I am new to JS and i have learned it with Stimulus and I use Rails.I have been trying to display the image I click  on from my gallery in my modal but it always shows me the first image of my gallery. I do not know how to target the src of my img. This is my index page.

```html
<div class="container mb-5">
  <h1 class='headers'>This is my personal art page</h1>
  <div class='image_container' id='app' data-controller="clickable_images">
    <% @personals.each do |personal| %>
      <div class='img-box'>
        <button data-action="click->clickable_images#expandImage"><%= cl_image_tag personal.image.key, class: 'personal_img', data: { target: "image" } %></button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal" data-controller="slider" data-clickable_images-target="modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <%= cl_image_tag personal.image.key %>
            <button data-action="click->slider#close">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>`
```

And here are my two stimulus controllers. The modal opens and closes I just cannot seem to target the right thing. When I open my console and press on the images, it works, it shows that i click on different images, but how do i target the dynamic source to be able to display the clicked image in my modal?

```js
import { Controller } from "stimulus";

export default class extends Controller {

  open() {
    document.body.classList.add("modal-open");
    this.element.setAttribute("style", "display: block;");
    this.element.classList.add("show");
    document.body.innerHTML += '<div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>';
  }

  close() {
    document.body.classList.remove("modal-open");
    this.element.removeAttribute("style");
    this.element.classList.remove("show");
    document.getElementsByClassName("modal-backdrop")[0].remove();
  }
}
```

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["modal"];

  expandImage(event) {
    let sliderController = this.application.getControllerForElementAndIdentifier(
      this.modalTarget,
      "slider"
    );

    sliderController.open();

    console.log(event.currentTarget);
  }
}
```

Comment: `this.element` gives you the element that fired the event (the button). To get the image inside the button you can use for example `this.element.firstChild`.

Comment: @max `this.element` refers to controller's element https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/controllers#properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the original approach was that your cross referencing of controllers wa buggy.

```js
    let sliderController = this.application.getControllerForElementAndIdentifier(
      this.modalTarget,
      "slider"
    );
```

Here, you had `this.modalTarget` but your clickable images controller was outside the scope of the template loop. So it was picking up the modalTarget but just the first one every time. Stimulus would have given you back ALL of the modals if you used `this.modalTargets`, but then you would need a way to know which button clicked which 'index' on those targets.

---

I would recommend you keep this approach simple, just have one controller (e.g. a `viewbox` controller) that does what you need in one class. You can call this clickable-images, but that's very long and simple is good.

So, let's revise the HTML;

1. Remember accessibility, avoid trying to make non-button things clickable, bu if you must, make sure you include the right attributes. Also, button type should be 'button', otherwise the browser will treat it as a submit and reload the page. Give buttons a label also.
2. Put the controller on your wrapper div.img-box
3. No need for a target on the preview image, as it's not used
4. Make the modal a target of the viewbox controller

```html
<div class="container mb-5">
  <h1 class='headers'>This is my personal art page</h1>
  <div class='image_container' id='app'>
    <% @personals.each do |personal| %>
      <div class='img-box' data-controller="viewbox">
        <div class='preview-container'>
          <button type="button" data-action="click->viewbox#open">View</button>
          <%= cl_image_tag personal.image.key, class: 'personal_img' %>
        </div>
        <div class="modal" data-viewbox-target="modal">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <%= cl_image_tag personal.image.key %>
              <button data-action="click->viewbox#close">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, let's revise the modal controller, it's almost exactly the same now but just that the modal content is a target.

```js
import { Controller } from "stimulus";

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ['modal'];

  open() {
    const modal = this.modalTarget;
    document.body.classList.add("modal-open");
    modal.setAttribute("style", "display: block;");
    modal.classList.add("show");
    document.body.innerHTML += '<div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>';
  }

  close() {
    const modal = this.modalTarget;
    document.body.classList.remove("modal-open");
    modal.removeAttribute("style");
    modal.classList.remove("show");
    document.getElementsByClassName("modal-backdrop")[0].remove();
  }
}
```

A small aside - it is much easier for people to answer Stimulus questions if you just use the actual HTML, not the Ruby on Rails template syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. And thank you about the last comment I will keep that in mind for next time.